# Ajax not sending data to php file GET/POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, iis

I'm using IIS server. when send ajax send request, i can see firebug console sent data.

[image]

but when i get data in php side (`$_GET['Email']`) getting error notice,
**Undefined index: Email**

when i run this application in Apache server this is running without any issue.

can you please any one know this ? or any extinction need to enable ?

Comment: Can you try `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET`

Comment: I'm developed this application in wamp server but i have godaddy windows host (iis sever) when i run this on godaddy server i saw this issue. after that i was created this local iis server. same issue i found. i don't know why that happen. i think this is not only ajax.

Comment: wait i will try @Md.SahadatHossain

Comment: same issue, undefined index `$_REQUEST['Email']`

Comment: Would you please post your ajaxurl ?

Comment: In your php script `print_r($_GET)` It will give you all the params

Comment: i found this is only happen `GET` method. post data working.

Comment: empty array print @DipanwitaKundu :(

Comment: try `print_r($_REQUEST)` or `print_r($_POST);`